# How do I remove a user from an organization in Asana?

Tags: asana

When inviting users to an organization in Asana I made a typo in someone's email address and now I have this extra user that belongs to no-one and that pops up whenever we are mentioning that user:

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

I tried going to the settings of the only team I have, but that user is not there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the user from the organization / cancel invite:

In the left menu, click the gear icon next to the team you wish to edit, and select "Team Settings".
[image: Asana Team Settings]

Then switch to the "Members" tab, hover over the user and select "Cancel Invite"
[image: Asana Team Members page - Cancel Invite]

Comment: I tried that, but the user is not there. I updated the question accordingly.